# How to use getUsermedia once for multi connection in WebRTC？

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia, rtcmulticonnection

I'm using WebRTC to make multi video conference.
But I found when the different people come to my room, getUserMedia will be called.

Is there any method can only call getUsermedia once in beginning with multi connection in WebRTC?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `dontCaptureUserMedia=true`
2. Invoke `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` yourselves
3. Push stream to `attachStreams` array
4. Fire `onstream` even or manually set `localVideo.srcObject=stream`
5. Open or join a room

**Example:**

```
// first step
connection.dontCaptureUserMedia = true;

// seocond step
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
}).then(function(stream) {
    // third step
    stream.isVideo = true;
    connection.attachStreams = [stream];

    // fourth step
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.playsinline = true;
    video.controls = true;
    video.muted = true;
    video.srcObject = stream;
    connection.onstream({
        stream: stream,
        type: 'local',
        streamid: stream.id,
        mediaElement: video
    });

    // last step: now open or join a room
    connection.openOrJoin('your-room-id');
});
```

**How it works?**

1. `dontCaptureUserMedia` will ignore (bypass) any local getUserMedia invocation
2. `attachStreams` array will be used to share with remote parties

and rest of the code is casual.

Comment: This method is for RTCMultiConnection. >_<
I just use the native WebRTC, so i can't find  "attachStreams" to push my getusermedia stream.

Comment: For javascript based RTCPeerConnection native app, you can use this: `stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) { nativePeer.addTrack(track, stream); });` i.e. you can either use `addTrack` which is strongly recommended over `addStream`.